# Check if the table exists or not in shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I have something in mind. I am planning to check if the table exists in the webpage. For example,
in the below application, there is table displayed on the webpage. So I need to print somewhere on the webpage that the table exists. Something like, if it exists, then 1 or else 0.

Can we populate this?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
 DTOutput("tab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 output$tab <- renderDT({
   datatable(iris)
 }) 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```